# weird tail of line graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have a csv as below and I draw a line graph with x-axis as column 0, y-axis as column 1

[image]
my code:

```
    ax = df.plot(x=0, y=1, marker = 'D', markersize=4)
    plt.yscale('log')     
    plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(df[0])), labels=df[0], rotation=45)
    plt.savefig('DU_BER')
```

I found that if I plot with 'plt.yscale('log')', there appears to be a weird tail at xtick '31-40'.
but if I remove the 'plt.yscale('log')', the graph became normal.
How do I remove this annoying tail at xtick '31-40' when I use the 'plt.yscale('log')'?

with logscale:
[image]

without logscale:
[image]

Comment: `log 0 = -inf`, isn't it what you get?

Comment: the value of '31=40' is 4 tho, it has a dot on the graph but not sure why it extends to the ground....

Comment: Because you cannot have `0` in log scale; it's infinitely far below

Comment: You could try `df[df[1]>0].plot(x=0, y=1, ...)` to filter out the pesky points at minus infinity.